# How to count number of lines in a text file using SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to know how I can count the number of lines from a text file. I do not wish to print it to SAS output or log, but only display the total count of lines from a file.

Ex:
data one;
infile '';
(code for counting total number of lines?)

run;

Comment: Where do you want it, if not output/results or log?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know what you mean by display if you don't want it in the two places SAS typically displays things, but...

```
data _null_;
  infile "c:\temp\test.dat" end=eof;
  input;
  if eof then put "Lines read:" _n_;
run;
```

That would do the trick.  Just uses `_N_` (the number of iterations in the data step).

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. By no display I meant that I do not wish to print the entire text file to the log, but only generate a log message indicating the total lines in the text file.

Comment: Well then, this would do that.

Comment: Very tricky! Small and efficient. Thank you!